# Differentiability of $x/(1+|x|)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

$$\frac x{1+|x|}$$
Clearly the above function is not differentiable at $x=0$. Because $LHD= -1$ and $RHD=1$. But why does the graph of this function looks like it is differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: *How* is it clear to you that this function is not differentiable at $0$?

Answer (score 6):

The function *is* differentiable at $x=0$. Both the left-hand and right-hand derivatives are 1.

This is the *softsign function* of artificial neural networks. It is a good example of an [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) because it is differentiable, allowing classic machine learning techniques like backpropagation to be applied to networks using this function.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{1}{1+|h|}$$ and this tends to $1$ if $h$ tends to zero, so $$f'(0)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

*Left hand derivative:*

For $x<0$, the function is equal to $$\frac{x}{1-x}$$

The derivative of this is $$\frac{1\cdot (1-x) - (-1)\cdot x}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
and this value goes to $1$ as $x\to 0$.

---

*Right hand derivative:*

The function is equal to $$\frac{x}{1+x}$$

with a derivative of 
$$\frac{1\cdot(1+x) - 1\cdot x}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$ so the right hand derivative is also equal to $1$. The function is differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{d}{dx}|x|=\dfrac{|x|}{x}$ we have

\begin{eqnarray} \left(\frac{x}{1+|x|}\right)^\prime&=&\dfrac{1\cdot(1+|x|)-x\cdot\frac{|x|}{x}}{(1+|x|)^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}
 \end{eqnarray}

Thus if $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$, then $f^\prime(0)=1$.